# Heatmap binary data

Tags: r

I have a data.frame that looks like this:

> ```
> Variable    Column1    Column2       
>  a            1          1         
>  b            0          1        
>  c            1          1        
>  d            0          0           
> ...         .....      .....
> ```

I would like to heatmap  the data.frame so that the combination 1:1 has color for example "black", the combination 1:0 (and 0:1) the color "red" and the combination 0:0 the color "green". Globally, the data.frame has ~1500 rows. 
Moreover, I would like to maintain positions in the heatmap in the sense that variable a should not have to cluster with variable c.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: a heatmap makes no sense for you data, just a regular barplot with count is perfect, do you just wanna show how often the different combinations occur?? so just showing this `table(df$Column1, df$Column2)` visually?? in other words: what values should go on the x axis and which values should go on the y-axis??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base R has a heatmap function, called `heatmap`. You can run help(heatmap) for the details.

You can do a heatmap on binary data ... assuming that you have enough columns to make it worthwhile. The trick is to include `scale="none"` in the function call. This will ensure that your map uses only two colours - one for 1 and one for 0. The default uses a colour range that gives the heatmap a fuzzy effect. This is probably not what you want.

There are other arguments in heatmap that let you order the cases and variables in different ways.